Power BI: How to create cards with calc'd value using two other separate card visualizations
I am currently stuck with an issue on Power BI.
My desire is for the "Incidents Up/Down" and "Responses Up/Down" cards (bottom left) to be able to dynamically update as I alter the "Prior Year+Month" and "Current Year+Month" filters located in the top right corner. These filters currently affect the "April 2023 Incident Count" and "April 2023 Response Count" (Prior Year+Month filter), and the "April 2024 Incident Count" and "April 2024 Response Count" (Current Year+Month filter).
The table I am using is called "FireSTAT_Engine_Responses". The "Incident Count" and "Response Count" cards for both the prior and current years are both filtered on the columns "Agency = SFD", "Company is not (Blank)", and "Unit = E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E9, E10, E11, E12, E13, E14, T2, T3, T4". These cards are then further filtered down using the "Prior Year+Month" and "Current Year+Month" filters (top right corner) by the Year and Month columns located within the "FireState_Engine_Responses" table.
With the way I have this dashboard currently set up, would this request even be possible? Is there a better way to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I have tried using DAX formulas and scouring the internet for any and all resources to no avail. I have tried creating new measures and columns as well. I am stuck.

It's hard to help without seeing your data model, sample data and DAX code used to construct the visuals.

Assuming slicer 1 is only applied to the top row, and slicer 2 only to the middle row, right? It is possible using DAX however the two slicers will need to be coming from two different tables (ie you'll need to duplicate your Calendar/Date table). Alternatively, if you always want to compare the same month to the previous year, then you can just have the one slicer and use DAX Time Intelligence functions to give you previousYear-sameMotth values.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
